# 'Do' as a one-word short answer

Tags: grammar, abbreviations, politeness, do

- Example: - It's stuffy in here. Shall I open the window? + Do.
- Example: - Do you mind if I look at your paper? + No, please do.

What is the grammar behind this structure? When can it be used?

Comment: 'Do so' would be suitable if the Managing Director is telling one of the minions to get on with it. Or 'Do so'. But the generality of courteous people would say 'Please do'.

Comment: It may be short for "No, please do _it_"

Comment: It can be used as in your examples, to accept an offer to carry out an action or to answer a request for permission. Oxford Dictionaries (online) says that 'do' can be :  _Used in positive commands to give polite encouragement._

Answer (score 1):

"Do" is a verb.  In many cases, in English, one can omit the subject of a verb, or it's object (if an object is even expected), or possibly both, if the omitted terms are readily inferred from the context.

"Do", in this sense, is short for "You do that", and is a perfectly normal construction.

Answer (score 0):

So, as a native speaker, I would say that this isn't so much a question of grammar, but rather one of style.

'Do' as a single word answer simply means 'Please, by all means, go ahead and do that'. I know that this rather long-winded, but in many respects, that is the key point here. 'Do' as a single word answer is only really acceptable when it is accompanied by a tone of voice which is light-hearted and frivolous.

Having thought about it a bit, by using 'Do', you are implying that the question to which it is a response, e.g. 'May I open the window?', isn't at all necessary, and that you are merely answering the question to be polite (because to not answer it would be rude). In that sense, the idea of 'by all means do that' is a good long-form equivalent. It also tends to be accompanied by a flat-palm hand-gesture - in this example towards the window - as if to invite the person to go ahead and open it.

Some examples...
May I open the window? Do... (with flat-palm hand-gesture towards the window)
Is it okay if I make myself a cup of coffee? Do... (hand gesture towards the kettle)
Is it alright if I go to the toilet? Do... (flat-palm hand-gesture towards the toilet)

Weirdly, without the flat-palm hand-gesture, it seems more like a direct command, in which case you would say 'Do that!' anyway. 'Do' on its own in that scenario wouldn't mean much.

One media instance of this type of thing - though not the exact example - is in Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Askaban. Right at the very end when Harry and Hermoine are about to reenter the hospital ward, they meet Dumbledore. They then tell him that they completed their task successfully, to which he replies 'What task?' whilst clearly knowing exactly what they are talking about. If you imagine Harry asking 'may I open the window?' and Dumbledore saying 'Do' with the exact same tones of voice, that is a good representation of the idea behind this phrase. Sounds crazy, but hey!

Comment: Another similar media instance is Jean-Luc Picard's standard response to suggestions in Star Trek which was "Make it so". I always assumed that this was supposed to be a translation from Canadian French even though Patrick Stewart comes from West Yorkshire.